# how do i save transaction log to database

Tags: django, laravel, django-models, eloquent, django-views

good day guys,
I need your opinion on this problem. although am using Django for my project but am sure this problem is not tie to django alone. So, I am working on these services booking system. In my database I have 3 tables listed below:

1. User_Table with field
   •   Id
   •   Username
   •   Fullname
2. Services_Table with field
   •   Id
   •   name
   •   Price
3. Transaction_Table with field
   •   Id
   •   User_id
   •   Services_id  (many to many relationship)

When this services get booked, I send it to the transaction table using the user_id and services_id as foreign key for User Table and Services Table meaning it’s the id values that are saved.
When a client want to view his or her transaction history, I provide it by running the query:

price = transaction.service.price

service_name = transaction.service.name

total_cost = sum of all services selected

as not to present the user with id values for price and service_name.
now here is my problem, in future, if the admin decide to change the name and price of a service and the client goes back to view his old transaction log, the new value get populated cus I referenced them by ids which is not what I want, I want the client to see the old value as a receipt would be  even when I updated the services table.
What do you suggest I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You should record every transaction made and record the price and amount it totalled up to at the moment the txn was made. Transaction model should have fields to record every detail about the transaction.

This means:
You would have a txn_service table, where all services in a transaction are saved and linked to the transaction table.